# How to ignore the TargetSubID for the session key of a QuickFix session?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, camel-quickfix

Based on [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788283/is-it-correct-to-use-targetsubid-as-a-flag-for-test-data-in-fix-protocol), I would like to ignore the **TargetSubID** when it is sent. The following configuration is available:

```
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=Sender
TargetCompID=Target
```

And if the source system sends a **TargetSubID** "Sub", the following error occurs:

```
Unknown session: FIX.4.4:Sender->Target/Sub
```

Is it possible to tell QuickFix that it should use FIX.4.4:Sender->Target configuration and send the **TargetSubID** anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [camel-quickfix](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quickfix-component.html) so here is the answer for this one. You can set the parameter **sessionID** for the quickfix consumer and producer, so that the FIX message with TargetSubID will be send using the Session without TargetSubID.

Consumer

```
<from uri="quickfix:config?sessionID=FIX4.4:Sender->Target" />
```

Producer

```
<to uri="quickfix:config?sessionID=FIX.4.4:Sender->Target" />
```